# Individually selecting multiple strings using Ruby and regular expressions

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string of data which looks like this which is on one line.

```xml
<record xmlns:f="http://abc.com/">
<f:Table><f:Row><f:Cell>#1</f:Cell></f:Row><f:Row><f:Cell>Data 222</f:Cell></f:Row><f:Row>           <f:Cell>Version: v3</f:Cell></f:Row><f:Row><f:Cell>Serial Number: 000000000</f:Cell></f:Row> <f:Row><f:Cell>Signature: 123</f:Cell></f:Row><f:Row><f:Cell>Issuer:</f:Cell></f:Row><f:Row> <f:Cell>C=EE,</f:Cell></f:Row><f:Row><f:Cell>ST=ABC,</f:Cell></f:Row><f:Row><f:Cell>L=avavv,</f:Cell></f:Row><f:Row><f:Cell><f:HexDump><f:Line seq=""0x0000"" hex=""09 09 4f 3d 5a 65 72 6f 54 75 72 6e 61 72 6f 75"">..O=ABC</f:Line><f:Line seq=""0x0010"" hex=""6e 64 20 4f c3 9c 2c"">nd OÇ.,</f:Line></f:HexDump></f:Cell></f:Row><f:Row><f:Cell>OU=abc,</f:Cell></f:Row><f:Row><f:Cell>CN=trtrtrtr,</f:Cell></f:Row><f:Row><f:Cell>E=null,</f:Cell></f:Row><f:Row><f:Cell>Create: 03/03/2010 14:58</f:Cell></f:Row><f:Row><f:Cell>Expire: 04/02/2010 14:58</f:Cell></f:Row><f:Row><f:Cell>Subject:</f:Cell></f:Row><f:Row><f:Cell>C=EE,</f:Cell></f:Row><f:Row><f:Cell>ST=SS,</f:Cell></f:Row><f:Row><f:Cell>L=Tartu,</f:Cell></f:Row><f:Row><f:Cell><f:HexDump><f:Line seq=""0x0000"" hex=""09 09 4f 3d 5a 65 72 6f 54 75 72 6e 61 72 6f 75"">..O=ZeroTurnarou</f:Line><f:Line seq=""0x0010"" hex=""6e 64 20 4f c3 9c 2c"">nd OÇ.,</f:Line></f:HexDump></f:Cell></f:Row><f:Row><f:Cell>OU=KKK,</f:Cell></f:Row></f:Table>
```

My Ruby Regular expresion looks like this:

```xml
<f:HexDump>[\s\S]*,<\/f:Line><\/f:HexDump>
```

So I'm trying to remove everything (including the tags) between both of the `<f:HexDump>` and `<f:/HexDump>` tags but leaving the stuff in between.

The problem is my regex is selecting everything in between right up to the second `<f:/HexDump>` tag.

```xml
<f:HexDump><f:Line seq=""0x0000"" hex=""09 09 4f 3d 5a 65 72 6f 54 75 72 6e 61 72 6f 75"">..O=ABC</f:Line><f:Line seq=""0x0010"" hex=""6e 64 20 4f c3 9c 2c"">nd OÇ.,</f:Line></f:HexDump></f:Cell></f:Row><f:Row><f:Cell>OU=abc,</f:Cell></f:Row><f:Row><f:Cell>CN=trtrtrtr,</f:Cell></f:Row><f:Row><f:Cell>E=null,</f:Cell></f:Row><f:Row><f:Cell>Create: 03/03/2010 14:58</f:Cell></f:Row><f:Row><f:Cell>Expire: 04/02/2010 14:58</f:Cell></f:Row><f:Row><f:Cell>Subject:</f:Cell></f:Row><f:Row><f:Cell>C=EE,</f:Cell></f:Row><f:Row><f:Cell>ST=SS,</f:Cell></f:Row><f:Row><f:Cell>L=Tartu,</f:Cell></f:Row><f:Row><f:Cell><f:HexDump><f:Line seq=""0x0000"" hex=""09 09 4f 3d 5a 65 72 6f 54 75 72 6e 61 72 6f 75"">..O=ZeroTurnarou</f:Line><f:Line seq=""0x0010"" hex=""6e 64 20 4f c3 9c 2c"">nd OÇ.,</f:Line></f:HexDump>
```

Can this be done using Ruby regular expressions?

Comment: That's XML. You should parse XML as XML using an XML parser, not as text using a regular expression. Especially when you want to match nested things.

Comment: Yeah I know, I tried nokogiri but I've not had any success with getting to elements I need to remove. Probably because its badly formed.

Comment: You mean the `""`? Luckily, that can be fixed with a string replacement :) (If it's not that, then what errors does nokogiri give you?)

Comment: I don't really get an error as such. If I use this code:

doc = Nokogiri::XML(doc2)
doc.remove_namespaces!
node_values = doc.search('//HexDump/*') do |n|
 n.text
end
puts node_values

I can't get it to return anything. I did a string replacement and removed all of the "".

Comment: If your XML is malformed you're almost certainly *more* likely to get problems parsing it with regex than a proper XML parser. Malformed content is the #1 reason to use a parser instead of regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex:

```
/<f:HexDump>.*?<\/f:HexDump>/
```

The key here is making the part between the HexDump tags non-greedy by using the `?`.

Assuming your string is stored in str, you can get rid of all the HexDump tags doing:

```
str.gsub(/<f:HexDump>.*?<\/f:HexDump>/, '')
```

Note that you might want to enable multi-line mode for the regex (adding m to the end) if there can be return carriages between the tags.